# ArcGIS Pro SDK for .Net loading dlls and app.config settings

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am trying to use some third party dlls (Entity Framework and EntityFramework.SqlServer) in my arcgis Pro sdk module. However, whenever my code runs inside ArcMap pro, I get errors like this:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with
> invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'. Make sure the provider
> is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application
> config file.

I have several stand alone apps with exactly the same app.config file "entityFramework" section which all work fine:

```xml
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

During debug, I can see that the modules have loaded. In my program output I get messages like this:

> C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\ESRI\ArcGISPro\AssemblyCache{05b82a89-759c-4123-b178-75b72b968646}\EntityFramework.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled.

> 'ArcGISPro.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ArcGISPro.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\ESRI\ArcGISPro\AssemblyCache{05b82a89-759c-4123-b178-75b72b968646}\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled.

> 'ArcGISPro.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ArcGISPro.exe): Loaded 'Anonymously
> Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'.

> Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlServerCe\4.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled.

I wonder if anyone else has had a similar problem, if there is some reference or app.config setting I am missing. Or if ArcGIS pro sdk for .Net doesn't read the app.config?